# Probability - Finding the Support of a Joint Transformation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, transformation

> $$ f(x,y) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>              12xy(1-y) & \quad 0< x < 1, 0<y<1 \\
>              0 & \quad \text{elsewhere}
>          \end{array}
>      \right. $$
>
> Let $Z = XY^2$ and $W=Y$ be a joint transformation of $(X,Y)$.
>
> Find the support of $(Z,W)$.

I always have a hard time finding this support.

Is there a general method?

After analyzing the graphs of the joint pdfs, I'm thinking it might be $$0<z<w^2,0<w<1$$ although I'm very unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

We know that: $0<x<1$, $0<y<1$, $Z=XY^2$ and $W=Y$

first for $Z$:
$$0<y<1 \implies 0<y^2<1 \implies 0<xy^2<1 \implies 0<z<1$$

for $W$, just replace $y$ by $w$: $0<y<1 \implies 0<w<1$